# warble aborted! lib/cpp (No such file or directory)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, jrubyonrails

I am trying to create war to deploy. But I get error warble aborted!
lib/cpp (No such file or directory) whenever i fire warble war command

$ warble war

rm -f ROOT.war

Creating ROOT.war

warble aborted!

lib/cpp (No such file or directory)
WarblerJar.java:61:in `create_jar'

how do i solve this problem

Comment: Do you have g++ or another c++ compiler installed on the machine?  The error seems to be indicating that you do not.

Comment: I do have them isntalled

Answer (score 0):

I do not think the error has anything to do with g++ or c++. The code in question is trying to zip the contents up. https://github.com/jruby/warbler/blob/master/ext/WarblerJar.java For some reason it is under the assumption that lib/cpp is something which should be zipped up or where it is attempting to create the new jar file.

I created a test rails app call ROOT to see if it was some strange naming issue, but it worked.

The config/warble.rb file contains a listing of included dirs

```
    config.dirs = %w(app config lib log vendor tmp)
```

Perhaps there's a typo in there? Try deleting the lib entry as a step in debugging.

Or if it's something beyond your control, perhaps adding the lib/cpp entry to

```
    config.excludes = FileList["lib/cpp"]
```